# Adding two images with occlusions to one image without occlusions in opencv

Tags: opencv

Given image a and b:

[image]
[image]

and the current result:

[image]

i want to add a and b together to c and remove the line where they are added.

```
auto a = imread(a_path);
auto b = imread(b_path);
cv::Mat c;
add(a, b,c);
imwrite(c_path, c);
```

what is the simplest solution that can do a better job then this simple add that i am doing now.

Looking for a solution in opencv.

Answer (score 0):

I vent with an impainting method as it was the onlything i had from prior projects. Might be something more simple, but this works.

```
auto a = imread(a_path);
auto b = imread(b_path);

std::vector<std::vector<Point> > ca, cb;
std::vector<Vec4i> ah, bh;

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(a, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
findContours(gray, ca, ah, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

cv::cvtColor(b, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
findContours(gray, cb, bh, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

cv::Mat m1 = cv::Mat::zeros(256, 256, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat m2 = cv::Mat::zeros(256, 256, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat m3 = cv::Mat::zeros(256, 256, CV_8UC1);

drawContours(m1, ca, 0, 255,-1);
drawContours(m2, cb, 0, 255,-1);
bitwise_and(m1, m2, m3);

cv::Mat c;
add(a, b,c);    
inpaint(c, m3, c, 5, INPAINT_NS);

imwrite(c_path, c);
```

and heres the result:
[image]